# PHPUnit and Ubuntu - Issues with include path after Installation with PEAR

Tags: php, phpunit

I need to install PHPUnit for a web dev project on my Ubuntu box, but am having serious issues.  Using suggestions from various sources, I've installed via `pear` and tried the following:

- Currently, `phpunit --version` returns

  ```
  PHPUnit 3.7.20 by Sebastian Bergman
  ```

when in `/usr/share` but throws errors everywhere else.

- My `include path` is

  ```
  include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/php/PEAR:/usr/share/php/File/Iterator"
  ```
- I've tried different variations ranging from simple `/usr/share/php` to the full string above.  `PEAR` is in all caps since that is the folder it is in.
- Executing with a test case results in

  ```
  PHP Warning:  require_once(File/Iterator/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: 
  No such file or directory in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 64
  PHP Stack trace:
  PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
  PHP   2. require() /usr/bin/phpunit:43
  PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 
  'File/Iterator/Autoload.php'(include_path='/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php')
  in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 64
  ```
- `pear list -c phpunit` returns

  ```
  Installed packages, channel pear.phpunit.de:
  ============================================
  Package            Version State
  File_Iterator      1.3.3   stable
  PHPUnit            3.7.20  stable
  PHPUnit_MockObject 1.2.3   stable
  PHP_CodeCoverage   1.2.10  stable
  PHP_Invoker        1.1.2   stable
  PHP_Timer          1.0.3   stable
  PHP_TokenStream    1.1.5   stable
  Text_Template      1.1.2   stable
  ```
- I've confirmed that `Autoload.php` exist at both `php/PHPUnit/` and `php/File/Iterator/`
- My loaded `php.ini` file is at `/etc/php5/cli.php.ini1 as verified by

  ```
  php --info | grep "onfiguration"
  ```

Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: add `/usr/share`  to the include path

Comment: You might get faster or better answers on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: @Orangepill, didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Search for a file on your computer that is called Autoload.php and is in a file structure like this:
`../File/Iterator/Autoload.php`

Now open the file that throws the error (`/usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php` in your case) and include a `set_include_path` statement that points to the absolute path of that file.

You seem to have a very similar problem to what I experienced on Mac OSX. For more information look at this [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726186/phpunit-fatal-error-and-include-path/16426746#16426746). If all of this doesn't help, try to install with [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/), which I have heard doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For recent projects, I'm using [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) to install PHPUnit and the other related tools. It's quite easy:

```
## ... rest of the composer.json file
# "php -f composer.phar update --dev" to install

"require-dev": {
  "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
},
```

I also then have a shell script to actually run the PHPUnit command-line tool from the ./vendor/bin/ directory where a link to the locally installed script is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Alister](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16745200/1069375)'s answer, relying on [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/),
but I prefer to deploy the updated [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html) globally across my projects with:

```
composer.phar global require "phpunit/phpunit=dev-master"
```

That way, when I am at the root dir of my Symfony project, I can just run

```
~/.composer/vendor/bin/phpunit -c app/ -v --filter testFireNotifications |tee phpunit.log
```

That last bit with *--filter* was to run something selectively (actually, more for fast web automation via crontab, than testing...)

Even on a current Ubuntu 14.04.2 server, the repo is stuck with an outdated PHPUnit 3.7.28 "stable", so I sidestep the OS-provided one with this custom install that won't conflict (I haven't put  `~/.composer/vendor/bin` in my **PATH**).